# angular, mousewheel event not work in iphone safari

Tags: angular, safari

I try to angular `mousewheel` event in my project, the event is worked in macbook safari, but not work in iphone safari

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMousewheel(event) {
   console.log(event.wheelDelta)
}
```

I cannot see the `console.log` display in mobile [development](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-iphone) mode.That it did not operate successfully.

For example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1uftvc?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

I need to know if the mouse is currently sliding up or down

Comment: MDN can help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event

Comment: `wheel` event also does not work.

Comment: evaluate the possibility to make reproducible your case, a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1uftvc?file=src/app/hello.component.ts